# MySQL API - restricting records

Tags: mysql, database, api

It seems that MySQL provides some sort of API interface to it. I have never used it, but I think it would be an interesting feature if I could:

- Specify which tables a user has access to
- Restrict read, update, and delete operations only to records the users created (so an ownership concept needs to be supported)

Will the API support that? If not, are there any other solutions that might allow me to do so?

Comment: *"It seems that MySQL provides some sort of API interface to it."* Uhmm, yeah, it's not particularly useful otherwise.

Comment: Seems like they just added this last year: http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/09/MySQL-REST. Was MySQL not particularly useful prior to then?

Comment: They've just added a *REST* API.  This is why we need to be careful with our terminology.  API is "Application Programming Interface" and it implies nothing about HTTP.

Comment: Are there any rdbms that give you that level of cell-level security like Accumulo. No. That's why the NSA designed it (for bigdata). But data none the less.

Answer (score 1):

As the author of [mysql-crud-api](https://github.com/mevdschee/mysql-crud-api) I can say that I understand your question. Although the permission rules regarding tables and/or users are application specific and should thus need to be configurable.

You may want to read about [multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy). You may want to support multiple users, but the ownership and permissions may vary between applications. That is why I think the tool you are looking for does not exist.

In order to support multitenancy [mysql-crud-api](https://github.com/mevdschee/mysql-crud-api) supports a multi-database mode. Using MySQL's built-in permission system you can use it to partition the database.

Not sure this helps you, as I do not know what you want to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a MySQL API for python and it lets you directly interact with your databases by name (an empty string in the database name parameter will get you to your root database where you can create databases, grant all permissions, etc). You are able to execute sql queries directly on the database.

Comment: You didn't address my question about the record level controls.

Comment: You can grant permissions to other users from the api using an sql query, if that is what you are wanting to do. If not, I'm unclear, and could you rephrase?

Comment: Say there is a table with 10 records. Assume that User-A created 2 of those records. When User-A accesses the table, I want that user only be able to access those two records.

Comment: You would need to add a "created_by" row to your table with the users name saved when they create it and filter based on that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL *is* an API to a database; there are numerous other interfaces supported as well (either that compile into SQL or that use some other API).

You question appears to be more about row-level permissioning than about a particular API.  MySQL does not have a built-in permissioning system at the row-level.  A quick glance at the web (Google:  "MySQL row level permissions") yields hits such as [this](https://www.sqlmaestro.com/resources/all/row_level_security_mysql/).